# how to remove data from hashtable for a particular date

Tags: java, vector, hashtable

I am trying to remove data from hashtable for a particular date,the hashtable is of type (String,vector).Initially i am checking if hashtable contains the usrDate if yes then i need to remove all the data frm hashtable only for usrDate and add the new data that is listEvents.But the contains from hashtable for other dates should not be deleted.

```
listEvents.addElement(eventBean);//new data is here
for (int i = 0; i < listEvents.size();i++) {
    EventData e = (EventData)listEvents.elementAt(i);
}

//checking if hashtable has given date
if (listUserEvents.containsKey(usrDate)) { 
    Vector info = (Vector)listUserEvents.get(usrDate);

    info.addElement(eventBean);
    listUserEvents.put(usrDate,info);
} else {                                             
    listUserEvents.put(usrDate,listEvents);
}
```

i just want to add listEvents to the hashtable for the given date,without affecting the other data in hashtable which has data for some other dates.

```
 private Hashtable getEvents(String usrDate, String timezone) {
               try {

                       listUserEvents = getUserInfo();
                       listEvents = new Vector();

                       Calendar calendarLocalEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
                       // fetches time zone
                       TimeZone timeZoneEvent = calendarLocalEvent.getTimeZone();
                       System.out.println("Time Zone first-->"
                                       + timeZoneEvent.getDefault());
                       if (timezone.equals(timeZoneEvent.getDefault())) {
                               ;
                       } else {
                               TimeZone timeZoneChange = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone);
                               System.out.println("Time Zone change-->" +timeZoneChange);
                               Device.setTimeZone(timeZoneChange);

                       }
                       EventList eventList = (EventList) PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(
                                       PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);

                       Enumeration events = eventList.items();

                       while (events.hasMoreElements()) {
                               System.out.println("in while");
                               Event event = (Event) events.nextElement();

                               if (eventList.isSupportedField(Event.START)
                                               && event.countValues(Event.START) > 0)
{
                                       long start = event.getDate(Event.START, 0);
                                       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                       "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
                                       SimpleDateFormat sdf_start = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                                       SimpleDateFormat sdf_start_min = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
                                       String dateString = sdf.formatLocal(start);
                                       String timeString = sdf_start.formatLocal(start);
                                       String hour = sdf_start_min.formatLocal(start);
                                       SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
                                       String date = sdf1.formatLocal(start);
                                       System.out.println("dates are :" + date +"user" + usrDate);
                                       if (usrDate.equalsIgnoreCase(date)) {
                                               System.out.println("dates are equal:" +date);
                                               EventData eventBean = new EventData();

                                               if (eventList.isSupportedField(Event.END)
                                                               && event.countValues(Event.END) > 0) {
                                                       long end = event.getDate(Event.END, 0);
                                                       SimpleDateFormat sdform = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                                       "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm");
                                                       SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                                       "HH:mm");
                                                       SimpleDateFormat sdfhr = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
                                                       String dateString1 =sdform.formatLocal(end);
                                                       String timeString1 =sdfTime.formatLocal(end);
                                                       String hr = sdfhr.formatLocal(end);
                                                       eventBean.setStartHr(hour);
                                                       eventBean.setEndHr(hr);
                                                       eventBean.setStartTime(timeString);
                                                       eventBean.setEndTime(timeString1);
                                                       eventBean.setStartDate(dateString);
                                                       eventBean.setEndDate(dateString1);

                                                       // Dialog.alert("equal startdate" + dateString);
                                                       // Dialog.alert("equal end date"+ dateString1);
                                               }
                                               if (eventList.isSupportedField(Event.LOCATION)
                                                               && event.countValues(Event.LOCATION) > 0) {
                                                       String location = event
                                                                      .getString(Event.LOCATION, 0);
                                                       eventBean.setLocation(location);
                                                       // Dialog.alert("equal location"+ location);
                                               }
                                               if (eventList.isSupportedField(Event.SUMMARY)
                                                               && event.countValues(Event.SUMMARY) > 0) {
                                                       String subject = event.getString(Event.SUMMARY, 0);
                                                       eventBean.setSummary(subject);
                                                       // Dialog.alert("equal subject" +subject);
                                               }
                                               eventBean.setUserDate(usrDate);
                                               eventBean.setTimeZone(timezone);
                                               listEvents.addElement(eventBean);
                                               System.out.println("the size bf hashis"
                                                               + listEvents.size());
                                               for (int i = 0; i < listEvents.size();i++) {
                                                       EventData e = (EventData)listEvents.elementAt(i);
                                                       System.out.println("so thesummary is ::"
                                                                       + e.getSummary());
                                               }
                                         //  for(int i=0;i<listUserEvents.size();i++){
                                               if (listUserEvents.containsKey(usrDate)) {

                                                    //  listUserEvents.remove(usrDate);
                                                       Vector info = (Vector)listUserEvents.get(usrDate);
                                                       System.out.println("the size in getEvents is"
                                                                       + info.size());
                                                       if(info.contains(usrDate)){
                                                           System.out.println("in info");
                                                       } 
                                                       info.addElement(eventBean);
                                                       System.out.println("vector size info is"
                                                                       + info.size());
                                                       listUserEvents.put(usrDate,info);
                                               } else {
                                                       System.out.println("in else of getevent" +listEvents.size());
                                                       listUserEvents.put(usrDate,listEvents);
                                               }
                                        //    }

                                       } else {
                                               // Dialog.alert("not equal");
                                       }

                               }

                       }
                       Device.setTimeZone(timeZoneEvent);
                       Calendar calendarLocalLastEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
                       // fetches time zone
                       TimeZone timeZoneEventLast =calendarLocalLastEvent.getTimeZone();
                       System.out.println("Time Zone last-->"
                                       + timeZoneEventLast.getDefault());

               } catch (PIMException e) {
                       // //Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());
               }
               System.out.println("size in hashtable " + listUserEvents.size());
               return listUserEvents;

       }
```

Comment: Well, either your hashtable key must be the date, or you need to iterate through all the hashtable entries.  If you want to remove an entry you remove it with `remove(key)`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where are you facing the issue?

Comment: @HotLicks i have used remove(key) but it dint worked,can you please modify the snippet and show with example

Comment: @sheetal_roswal: When you call `containsKey(key)` on your hashtable, does it return `false`? Or does `remove(key)` returns `null`?

Comment: @KuldeepJain i am facing issue with hashtable,i need to check in hashtable if it has usrDate if yes  delete the data from hashtable for that date and add the new contents to it for that date

Comment: contains(key) returns true ,can u please edit and show me

Answer (score 1):

It must be something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i<listUserEvents.size();i++)
{

    if (listUserEvents.containsKey(usrDate)){

     listUserEvents.remove(usrDate);

    }
```

}

Comment: its not working i have copied the entire function here http://codepad.org/6hFplePX

Comment: can you paste the entire class with the main method? I think It will help to me and others in the main post

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how this works:

```
    Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    numbers.put("one", 1);
    numbers.put("two", 2);

    if (numbers.containsKey("two")) {
        numbers.put("two", 222);
    }
```

What are you having difficulty at? Moreover what is the type of your `Hashtable` key? Is it `java.util.Date` or something else?

Comment: hashtable is of type (String Vector<bean>)

Comment: i have code somethinh as in http://codepad.org/6hFplePX,  remove is giving an exception